# How to redo when using VsVim?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsvim

I'm using VS 2010 + latest VsVim. Looks like Vim <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not work in VsVim. Is that true?

VS handled <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, saying: `(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VsVim allows you to control whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is handled by Visual Studio or VsVim itself.

At the bottom of a source file (e.g. *.cs) you should see the VsVim command line and an Options button. Clicking the Options button will give you a menu that lists various keyboard shortcuts and allows you to choose which application should handle them.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work for some reason in VS 2015. In my case, VS still waits for the second key chord. Any idea?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler With newer versions of VsVim the keyboard bindings have moved into their own settings page. Can you check Tools > Options > VsVim > Keyboard to see if Ctrl + R is being handled by VsVim?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is an Option button in after the VsVim command line. But even if I choose to VsVim to handle Ctrl+R, VS is still handling Ctrl+R and complains: '(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...'
I just tried to change this setting and let VS handle Ctrl+R, then change it back to VsVim. But still can't redo a previously undoed editting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you check Tools > Options > VsVim > Keyboard to see if Ctrl + R is being handled by VsVim?
2. `Ctrl + Z` may helps to redo in VsVim2022.